# `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT` between solo chain and para chain

Tags: cumulus

From Substrate:

https://github.dev/paritytech/substrate/blob/68d00e2d5132ef32e564e0320e89dfac57e1c46e/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L179

```rs
/// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block time, with maximum proof size.
const MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT: Weight = Weight::from_parts(
    WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND.saturating_mul(2),  // here
    u64::MAX
);
```

From Cumulus:

https://github.dev/paritytech/cumulus/blob/b97eb8d369e8a3e61cf7efffe184756fd75bad96/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L220

```rs
/// We allow for .5 seconds of compute with a 12 second average block time.
pub const MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT: Weight = Weight::from_parts(
    WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND.saturating_div(2),  // here
    polkadot_primitives::MAX_POV_SIZE as u64,
);
```

Generally, the block time for solo chains is 6s and for para chains 12s.

But the block max weight of a solo chain is 4 times that of para chain, doesn't this seem reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Generally, the block time for solo chains is 6s and for para chains 12s.

This is the first misunderstanding, this is the slot duration aka the interval in that your chain is building blocks. For solo chains you can use whatever value you want as slot duration. You just need to ensure that this time is bigger than the block time and still leaves enough time to propagate the block in the network. For Parachains indeed the slot duration isn't currently changeable. In the future you will be able to change this when asynchronous backing is implemented.

The block time is the actual time the block can take to import on your reference hardware. For Parachains this is currently set to 500ms to ensure that a PoV can be build, send to relay chain validators and validated on these relay chain validators. The block time can also be increased with asynchronous backing, but there will also be some upper maximum set by the relay chain.

> But the block max weight of a solo chain is 4 times that of para chain, doesn't this seem reasonable?

Yes that is reasonable. Given what I have written above, it hopefully explains you why.